# How do you block javascript slideshow animations in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript

Is it possible to disable javascript slideshow animations in Firefox?

A lot of news sites have delayed slide shows. It really irritates me when I'm reading a headline and it disappears. Is there a way to block this? [Here's](http://www.tulsaworld.com/) an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RightToClick](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/righttoclick/) extension does this easily -- just check "disable page timers" and nothing else. The other Javascript on the page will still work, so this will work with most sites.

This may have the additional benefit of blocking the timed popups that gray out the page you're trying to read.

Comment: This didn't work for me. For example, the slideshow on this page still runs: http://www.opb.org/kmhd/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It takes a little finesse, but well worth your peace of mind.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/

It allows JavaScript, Java and other executable content to run only from trusted domains
 of your choice, e.g. your home-banking web site, guarding your "trust boundaries" against
 cross-site scripting attacks (XSS), cross-zone DNS rebinding / CSRF attacks (router hacking)
 and Clickjacking attempts, thanks to its unique ClearClick technology. 
It also implements the DoNotTrack tracking opt-out proposal by default.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way with NoScript to block all Javascript slideshow animations?

Comment: no every site uses a different host, and not every slideshow will use same variables. As example tulsaworld.com if you block all ajax.aspnet*.com you remove there slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried up [Yesscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yesscript/) , its an javascript blacklist where one can just block specific scripts of the webpage

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Would this be less of a hassle than noscript?